# How to increase RAM memory for cluster in couchbase?

Tags: couchbase

For example I have created cluster with 1GB RAM memory per node. After some time I want to increase RAM memory for claster for example to 2GB per node. I assumed that I can do that through Couchbase Console. But "edit" button is disabled for every node.

So can someone advise me the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I love that Random Access Memory memory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do so with the couchbase-cli utility that is installed with Couchbase.  This tool should be located with the other Couchbase binaries on your system (e.g., C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin).

From the command line:

`c:\>couchbase-cli cluster-init -c <CLUSTER_IP> -u <USERNAME> -p <PASSWORD> --cluster-init-ramsize=<NEW_RAM_SIZE>`

With actual values:

`c:\>couchbase-cli cluster-init -c 127.0.0.1:8091 -u Administrator -p s3cr3t --cluster-init-ramsize=4096`

More information may be found at http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/couchbase-admin-cmdline-couchbase-cli.html

Answer (score 0):

Hello find this page while working something similar. For me that code works.

```
couchbase-cli setting-cluster -c <SERVER/LOCAL IP ADDRESS> -u <USERNAME> -p <PASSWORD> --cluster-ramsize=768
```

I have already up and running on my local so I/you can update it accordingly.